# How to shorten the file name/path to an image so it works on all machines

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml, search-path

in my c++ program using the sfml library and xcode, when I load an image I need to load it like `picture.loadFromFile("Users/username/Desktop/Xcode/Game/Sprites/MyImage.png")` is there anyway I can shorten that path to just `"Game/Sprites/MyImage.png"`. Once again I am using xcode and a mac. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Yes there's a way to get an abbreviated path, although it probably would help to see your efforts first.

Comment: On a Mac you normally put your application's files in the "application bundle". You can read about them in XCode's help.

Comment: I will look more into that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
#include <regex>

std::string full_path = "Users/username/Desktop/Xcode/Game/Sprites/MyImage.png";
std::smatch _match;
std::regex _regex("Game.*");
if(std::regex_search(full_path, _match, _regex))
  std::string relative_path = _match.str(); //"Game/Sprites/MyImage.png"
```

Comment: thanks this did the trick, but if I were to run on this on another computer I would have to change the "Users/username/Desktop/Xcode/etc..."

Comment: Based on your question I assumed you always know the full path and you always have a common directory to use in the regex search.